# Logical scrolling no longer working when applying a itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When applying a itemsControl i found that logical scrolling (`canContentScroll="true"`) no longer seems t be working.

With logical scrolling i mean viewing item per item when clicking for example 2 navigation buttons that moves the `scrollviewer`.

The content of the `itemControl` is as the following:

```
  <Grid Height="70" Width="900">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftScrollRow2" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="HorizontalContentRow2" Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RightScrollRow2" Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <RepeatButton Content="left" x:Name="btnLeft" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonStyleLeft}" Click="btnLeft_Click"></RepeatButton>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="sv" CanContentScroll="True" Margin="0" Height="73" >
                    <ListBox  x:Name="list1" ItemsSource="{Binding Reg, ElementName=Window}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="TestButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="71" Width="151" 
                            Margin="5,0,10,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleTest}" 
                            Click="TestButton_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <RepeatButton Content="right" x:Name="btnRight" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonStyleRight}" Click="btnRight_Click"></RepeatButton>
            </Grid>
```

When i navigate the items that are being loaded in the stackpanel (buttons) only continues scrolling appears, and content slowly appears.

A possible solution to this would be using *`HorizontalOffSet`* but this involving giving a exactly distance which i think would not be a good solution at all.

Thanks in advance,
Jackz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about this differently.

I would add the scroll bar in the style. Read this and see the note in the Scrollbar section.
http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/03/18/itemscontrol-vs-listbox-vs-listview-in-wpf/